# Using Dynamic Variable to populate Form label/verbose name

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django. I want to populate a form for model Score with dynamic labels/verbose names from another model : Question.

Essentially, each user has 5 current questions which they are going to score in a form as either "yes" or "no"

I have the data for a User's current five questions saved in a dictionary and can pass this dictionary into the view or template, but do not know how to use a dictionary to population the labels/ verbose names for the form.

```
#Model
class Score(models.Model):
yesno = ((0,"No"),(1,"Yes"),)
oneScore =models.IntegerField(choices=yesno,default='none')
twoScore =models.IntegerField(choices=yesno,default='none')    
threeScore =models.IntegerField(choices=yesno,default='none')
fourScore =models.IntegerField(choices=yesno,default='none')
fiveScore =models.IntegerField(choices=yesno,default='none')
author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
date_created = models.DateTimeField(blank=False, null=False)
```

---

```
#Model
class QuestionManager(models.Manager):
    def current_for_user(self,user):
        question1 = Question.objects.filter(author=user,statementNumber=1).order_by('-id').first()
        question2 = Question.objects.filter(author=user,statementNumber=2).order_by('-id').first()
        question3 = Question.objects.filter(author=user,statementNumber=3).order_by('-id').first()
        question4 = Question.objects.filter(author=user,statementNumber=4).order_by('-id').first()
        question5 = Question.objects.filter(author=user,statementNumber=5).order_by('-id').first()

        question_list = {"1":question1,
                        "2":question2,
                        "3":question3,
                        "4":question4,
                        "5":question5}
        return question_list

class Question(models.Model):
    statementNumber=models.IntegerField(choices=NUMBER, default='1',verbose_name="The number of the statement")
    text = models.CharField(max_length=500,help_text="Enter your text", verbose_name="New Statement")
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(blank=False, null=False)
    objects=QuestionManager()
```

---

```
#Form
class ScoreForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Score
        fields = ('oneScore','twoScore','threeScore','fourScore','fiveScore','bigScore')
```

---

```
#View
def score(request):
    user = request.user
    questions = Question.objects.current_for_user(user)

    if request.method == "POST":
        questions = Question.objects.current_for_user(user)
        form = ScoreForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            score = form.save(commit=False)
            score.author = request.user
            score.save()
            return redirect('scoresheet',pk=score.pk)
    else:
        form = ScoreForm()

    return render(request,'MC/score.html',{'form': form,'questions':sorted(questions.items())})
```

Comment: Did you check https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried to use :  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)  ... to pull this data, but was still unsure how to modify the labels: eg: self.fields['oneScore'].label =

Comment: You can simpley change the label using `label` dict inside your `ModelForm` Meta class

Comment: Thanks Misra. I can figure out how to change the label to a static label ie 'label = {'oneScore':"xyz"}' but the challenge is assigning it to a variable from model Question that is changing based on user inputs! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you're after, but you can pass anything you like to the form:

```
class ScoreForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, questions, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for num, question in questions.items():
            self.fields.get('some_field').label = question


#View
def score(request):
    user = request.user
    questions = Question.objects.current_for_user(user)
    if:
        # ...
    else:
        form = ScoreForm(questions)

    return render(request,'MC/score.html',{'form': form})
```

Comment: Great, yeah basically needing to pass these details to the Form. `form = ScoreForm(questions)"` - I have added this which I thought was maybe what I was missing. Added the rest of the code or tried to assign Labels manually (realize that is not perfect : `{'oneScore': questions[0],'twoScore': questions[1],'threeScore': questions[2],'fourScore': questions[3],'fiveScore': questions[4],})` But still can't get label/verbose name to update on the form. Thanks again

Comment: Amazing. Got it to work. Thank you! I initially included the def __init__ in the meta class which did not work. Fixed it! Thanks again